# How to merge dictionary having same keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a data structure like this:

```
    [ {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': '304'}},

      {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': '2015-06-21 17:33:41'}},


      {'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807'}}, 

      {'CafeData': {'IsSoftwareOnly': '1'}}, 

      {'CafeData'{'IsPassportTCPIP': '1'}}
```

]

The output should like this:

```
 [ {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': '304','SnapshotCreationDate': '2015-06-21 17:33:41'}},

   {'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807','IsSoftwareOnly': '1','IsPassportTCPIP': '1'}} 
 
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict which creates a dict within the defaultdict anytime a new key is encountered.

```
import collections as co

dd = co.defaultdict(dict)

l = [ {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': '304'}},
      {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': '2015-06-21 17:33:41'}},
      {'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807'}}, 
      {'CafeData': {'IsSoftwareOnly': '1'}}, 
      {'CafeData': {'IsPassportTCPIP': '1'}} ]

for i in l: 
    for k,v in i.items(): 
        dd[k].update(v)
```

Result:

```
In [8]: dd
Out[8]: 
defaultdict(dict,
            {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': '304',
              'SnapshotCreationDate': '2015-06-21 17:33:41'},
             'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807',
              'IsSoftwareOnly': '1',
              'IsPassportTCPIP': '1'}})
```

Comment: Ah, I see that it's not exactly the end-result you wanted but I think it's a good substitute. You can access it like a list this way: `dd.items()`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
l = [ 
      {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': '304'}},
      {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': '2015-06-21 17:33:41'}},
      {'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807'}}, 
      {'CafeData': {'IsSoftwareOnly': '1'}}, 
      {'CafeData': {'IsPassportTCPIP': '1'}} 
]

mrgdict={}
    
for d in l:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key in mrgdict:
            mrgdict[key].update(value)
        else:
            mrgdict[key]=value

dict={}
l1=[]
    
for key,value in mrgdict.items():
    dict[key]=value
    l1.append(dict)
    dict={}
print(l1)
```