# How to merge nested dictionary having same keys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a data structure like this:

```
[ {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': '304'}},

  {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': '2015-06-21 17:33:41'}},


  {'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807'}}, 

  {'CafeData': {'IsSoftwareOnly': '1'}}, 

  {'CafeData'{'IsPassportTCPIP': '1'}} 

  {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': '777'}},

  {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': '2017-07-27 17:37:47'}},]
```

The output should like this:

```
 [ {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': '304','SnapshotCreationDate': '2015-06-21 17:33:41'}},

   {'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807','IsSoftwareOnly': '1','IsPassportTCPIP': '1'}} 
 
   {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': '777','SnapshotCreationDate': '2017-07-27 17:37:47'}},
]
```

or the output should like this:

```
[ {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotVersion': ['304','777'],
                'SnapshotCreationDate': ['2015-06-21 17:33:41','2017-07-27 17:37:47']}},

   {'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807','IsSoftwareOnly': '1','IsPassportTCPIP': '1'}} 

]
```

Comment: Did you not get your answer here already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328076/how-to-merge-dictionary-having-same-keys

Comment: @BuddyBobIII: the requirements in the original question were simpler. He edited that question today with this new variation, so I asked him to create a separate question.

Comment: No this is different ,the output is different.The person who give the right answer suggest me to create a new question.

Comment: Ok got it! Just wondering why you posted the same question twice, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No problem,this is really really very very hard for me,I tried about a whole day,and can't make it!!

Comment: Yo have a typo in the 3rd *CafeData* key. So the list elements are dictionary with a single key and the value another dictionary?

Comment: @mechanical_meat Hi sir ,I updated the question to make it easier, can you help to check, really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: What is the rule that tells you which `'SnapshotVersion'` corresponds to what `'SnapshotCreationDate'`? What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you expect every top-level dict to have a single key? What should happen if that assumption is violated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could use a for loop and keep track of the last key that was merged.

```
from pprint import pprint

data = [
    {"SNAPSHOT": {"SnapshotVersion": "304"}},
    {"SNAPSHOT": {"SnapshotCreationDate": "2015-06-21 17:33:41"}},
    {"CafeData": {"CafeVersion": "2807"}},
    {"CafeData": {"IsSoftwareOnly": "1"}},
    {"CafeData": {"IsPassportTCPIP": "1"}},
    {"SNAPSHOT": {"SnapshotVersion": "777"}},
    {"SNAPSHOT": {"SnapshotCreationDate": "2017-07-27 17:37:47"}},
]

last_key = None
grouped = []
for value in data:
    # Easy way to get the key of a dict with one key
    curr_key = next(iter(value))
    # Decide if we should work on the next entry
    if last_key is None or curr_key != last_key:
        grouped.append(value)
    else:
        # update the last value in the group with the new data
        grouped[-1][curr_key].update(value[curr_key])
    # Move to the next item
    last_key = curr_key

pprint(grouped)
```

```
[{'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': '2015-06-21 17:33:41',
               'SnapshotVersion': '304'}},
 {'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807',
               'IsPassportTCPIP': '1',
               'IsSoftwareOnly': '1'}},
 {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': '2017-07-27 17:37:47',
               'SnapshotVersion': '777'}}]
```

Option 2 is similar, but for grouped I would just use a dict. In this case  you don't need to know about the last key.

Also you need to make some assumptions on how to merge vales if there are key collisions in the nested dict.

```
grouped = {}
for value in data:
    curr_key = next(iter(value))
    curr_value = value[curr_key]
    group = grouped.setdefault(curr_key, {})

    for sub_key, sub_value in curr_value.items():
        # check if you need to merge
        if sub_key in group:
            # If the key is already present, but is not a list, make it one
            if not isinstance(group[sub_key], list):
                group[sub_key] = [group[sub_key]]
            # Add the new value to the list
            group[sub_key].append(sub_value)
        else:
            # Otherwise just copy it over
            group[sub_key] = sub_value

pprint(grouped)
```

```
{'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807',
              'IsPassportTCPIP': '1',
              'IsSoftwareOnly': '1'},
 'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': ['2015-06-21 17:33:41',
                                       '2017-07-27 17:37:47'],
              'SnapshotVersion': ['304', '777']}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant that uses [[Python.Docs]: itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import itertools as it
from pprint import pprint as pp


l = [
    {"SNAPSHOT": {"SnapshotVersion": "304"}},
    {"SNAPSHOT": {"SnapshotCreationDate": "2015-06-21 17:33:41"}},
    {"CafeData": {"CafeVersion": "2807"}},
    {"CafeData": {"IsSoftwareOnly": "1"}},
    {"CafeData": {"IsPassportTCPIP": "1"}},
    {"SNAPSHOT": {"SnapshotVersion": "777"}},
    {"SNAPSHOT": {"SnapshotCreationDate": "2017-07-27 17:37:47"}},
]

def main(*argv):
    res = []
    for k, g in it.groupby(l, key=lambda x: next(iter(x))):
        res_item = {}
        for item in g:
            res_item.update(item[k])
        res.append({k: res_item})
    pp(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q067328076]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> [{'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': '2015-06-21 17:33:41',
>                'SnapshotVersion': '304'}},
>  {'CafeData': {'CafeVersion': '2807',
>                'IsPassportTCPIP': '1',
>                'IsSoftwareOnly': '1'}},
>  {'SNAPSHOT': {'SnapshotCreationDate': '2017-07-27 17:37:47',
>                'SnapshotVersion': '777'}}]
>
> Done.
> ```